# Initialize a variable and print its value on every frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a "health" property for an object. I want health to equal 100 at the start of the game, and print the health every frame so I can debug.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class healthScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        public int health = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This code doesn't really do anything. It's unclear what you are asking. If a property is supposed to be initialized to 100, do that in some init code. If you want to log values, there is a logger: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Logger.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug value each frame this will work:

```
public class healthScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   //Variable declaration
   private int _health;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start()
   {
        _health = 100;
   }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Debug.Log(_health);
    }
}
```

Your error was that you have defined your variable inside a Start method, so it's only visible inside this method. But when you define a variable inside the class but outside any method it's visible inside all the class. But as for variables visible inside and outside the class, where they are declared see [manual](http://csharp.net-informations.com/language/csharp-access-specifiers.htm) about access modifiers.

But I can suggest you a more convenient way:

```
public class healthScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Property
    public int Health
    {
        get { return _health; }
        set
        {
            _health = value;
            Debug.Log("Health changed to value: " + _health);
        }
    }

    //Variable declaration
    private int _health = 100;
}
```

In this case the you use properties to debug the value of your health. So every time you will change a value of health like that `Health = someIntValue` you'll get a console message about your current health level.